# Pattern matching a regex pattern in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, pattern-matching

In Scala, I have a regular expression pattern match like this:

```
val Regex = """(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})""".r
val Regex(year, month, day) = "2013/01/06"
```

The result is:

```
year: String = 2013
month: String = 01
day: String = 06
```

How can I accomplish a similar result in Haskell? In other words, can I match a regular expression containing groups and assign the groups to identifiers?

Comment: See chapter 8 of Real world Haskell: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html

Comment: I actually have the book open at this moment. The examples are outdated and several do not compile with GHC 7.4.

Comment: Looks like you are using dates: doesn't haskell has a date parsing library?

Comment: That is actually just a made-up example. My actual regex is much more complicated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "2013/01/06" =~ "([0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)" :: (String,String,String,[String])
("","2013/01/06","",["2013","01","06"])
```

(ghci 7.4.2 on OS X)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that return type and it works for me too. I'll post a small variant of your answer to include the extraction of the year, month, and day.

Comment: This does not work in the Posix parser, but does in the PCRE parser: `let (_, _, _, [year, month, day]) ="2013/01/06" =~ "(\\d{4})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})" :: (String,String,String,[String])`

Comment: Note that Text.Regex.Posix uses POSIX style regular expressions. It is also buggy on Windows. If you want this API, regex-tdfa-compat is a better choice

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187742/96233), the following works and is similar to my Scala version:

```
ghci> :m +Text.Regex.Posix
ghci> let (_, _, _, [year, month, day]) ="2013/01/06" =~ "([0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)" :: (String,String,String,[String])
ghci> year
"2013"
ghci> month
"01"
ghci> day
"06"
```