# Was ‘Text.Regex.Posix’ renamed or replaced?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I have the same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187577/pattern-matching-a-regex-pattern-in-haskell). However, both answers rely on the module `Text.Regex.Posix`. When I try to import it, I get

```
<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Posix’
    Perhaps you meant
      Text.Regex.Base (from regex-base-0.93.2@5g5YXZiScrKLs2R8SL8lg0)
      Text.Regex.PCRE (from regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35@B6GE2pWicek5lhKiWDiitR)
```

I've tried installing `regex-posix` as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29563505/165753), but the module still can't be found. So I was wondering if the functionality of `Text.Regex.Posix` was moved to the suggested modules `Text.Regex.Base` and `Text.Regex.PCRE`. My GHCi version is 7.10.3.

I'm a beginner in Haskell, so I might be missing something trivial.

Comment: You installed `regex-posix` and you have checked that you have install it for the compiler you are using? It happened to me to have one `ghc` from the OS distribution, and one manually installed and mix things up when installing packages...

Comment: Have you actually restarted ghci after installing `regex-posix`?

Comment: @Bakuriu, how can I check it? I did verify that both ghci and ghc have the same version.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yep

Comment: run `ghc-pkg list` and check that `regex-posix` is there.

Comment: @eric Thanks, it wasn't listed, and I just realized that I ran `cabal install` inside a sandbox dir. So please post your comment as an answer, and I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a package, make sure you are installing it to the appropriate location (globally, or in a sandbox). If cabal detects a sandbox, it will automatically install the package there (and it should say something to the effect of "detected sandbox at path/to/sandbox".)

You can always check which packages are installed in the global package index by running `ghc-pkg list`, or if cabal is using a sandbox, then `cabal sandbox hc-pkg list`.

Once you find out which package index cabal is using to compile a particular program, you can verify in the Hackage documentation that the desired functionality is present in the version you have installed.